# Problem with Tab Bar Controllers and Navigation Controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

### Description

I have a Tab Bar Controller with a navigation controller tab. The first and default tab is called "NowViewController". So in my AppDelegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I have the following:

```
// Set up MainWindow
NowViewController *nowViewController = [[[NowViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NowViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
nowViewController.context = [self managedObjectContext];
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = nowViewController;
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I need to pass the Core Data's managed object context which is why I instantiate a NowViewController object.

Now in my MainWindow.xib, I simply have the Navigation Controller set as follows:

[image: image 1]

### Problem

When launching the app, I get an empty page with the NewsViewController. When I click on the "Now" tab, I will then get a Navigation Bar that says "Root View Controller" when in fact it should say "Now". I already have `self.title = @"Now"` in the NowViewController's `ViewDidLoad` method.

Any ideas why I am getting this kind of problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED

I just changed my AppDelegate's line of code posted above to:

```
NowViewController *nowViewController = (NowViewController *) [self.navigationController topViewController];
nowViewController.context = [self managedObjectContext];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyWindow];
```

I would really appreciate though if someone would explain exactly this line of code:

`NowViewController *nowViewController = (NowViewController *) [self.navigationController topViewController]`